# openJPA mege() throwing UndeclaredThrowableException instead of OptimisticLockException

Tags: jpa, persistence, openjpa

When openjpa (version 2.3.0) persists an entity that has been modified in another context, it is throwing an UndeclaredThrowableException with the OptimisticLockException as the deepest ancestor exception.  My code and the actual exception are below.

Before I workaround the issue by catching UndeclaredThrowableException and parsing through the exception chain, I want to know

*Is my code wrong or is there some quirk of openjpa?*

**My code**

```
    IT savedEntity = null;
    try {
        savedEntity = em.merge(entity); // re-attach
        this.firePropertyChange(entity, savedEntity);
    } catch (OptimisticLockException ole) {
        logger.error("Error saving entity [" + entity.toString() + "]", ole);
        throw JpaExceptionFactory.createRecordChanged(ole, entity == null ? 0 : ((IDatabaseEntity) entity).getId(),
                entity == null ? "null entity" : entity.getClass().getName());
    } catch (PersistenceException he) {
        logger.error("Error saving entity [" + entity.toString() + "]", he);
        throw JpaExceptionFactory.createPersistence(he, entity == null ? 0 : ((IDatabaseEntity) entity).getId(),
                entity == null ? "null entity" : entity.getClass().getName());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.error("Error saving entity [" + entity.toString() + "]", t);
        throw JpaExceptionFactory.createUnknownDatabase(t, entity == null ? 0 : ((IDatabaseEntity) entity).getId(),
                entity == null ? "null entity" : entity.getClass().getName());
    } 


    return savedEntity;
```

**Exception**

```
2015-03-22 16:03:00,881 | ERROR | nelWorkerThread1 | AbstractEntity                   | 152 - com.easa.motordb.server.services - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Error saving entity [DcMotor [id=4655, version=4, powerUnits=0, powerValue=20.0, poles=0, manufacturer=test install, rpm=0, frameBase=asdf, frameSuffix=, framePrefix=asdf, model=, armVolts=0.0, shuntVolts=0.0, typeDesc=, armAmp=0.0, windingType=0, interPole=0, coreLength=0.0, coreDiam=0.0, slots=0, bars=0, turnsCoil=, slotPitch=0, commPitch=0, equalizers=0, equalizerPitch=0, shuntCoils=0, shuntCR=0.0, shuntTC1=0.0, shuntTC2=0.0, seriesCoils=0, seriesCR=0.0, seriesTC1=0.0, seriesTC2=0.0, ipCoils=0, ipCR=0.0, ipTC1=0.0, ipTC2=0.0, ctrBar=0, micaBar1=0, micaBar2=0, leadThrow4=, leadThrow5=, leadThrow6=, occurs=0, dataSource=, userName=, createDate=Wed Mar 11 11:00:00 EDT 2015, modifyDate=Sun Mar 22 16:03:00 EDT 2015, armWires=[], shuntWires=[], ipWires=[], seriesWires=[], eqWires=[], origId=0, motorDupKey=, coreUom=null, airGapDensity=0.0]]
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.merge(Unknown Source)
        at com.easa.motordb.services.jpa.AbstractEntity.save(AbstractEntity.java:395)
        at com.easa.motordb.services.jpa.DcMotorEntity.save(DcMotorEntity.java:126)
        at com.easa.motordb.services.jpa.DcMotorEntity.save(DcMotorEntity.java:22)
        at Proxyf1547343_5d2d_4cb2_90e9_351499ef7b89.save(Unknown Source)
        at Proxyf1547343_5d2d_4cb2_90e9_351499ef7b89.save(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_65]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context.transaction.impl.JTAEntityManagerHandler.invoke(JTAEntityManagerHandler.java:185)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.merge(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_65]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerProxyFactory$EMHandler.invoke(EntityManagerProxyFactory.java:31)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: An optimistic lock violation was detected when flushing object instance "com.easa.motordb.model.jpa.DcMotor-4655" to the data store.  This indicates that the object was concurrently modified in another transaction.
FailedObject: com.easa.motordb.model.jpa.DcMotor-4655
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.VersionAttachStrategy.compareVersion(VersionAttachStrategy.java:219)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.VersionAttachStrategy.attach(VersionAttachStrategy.java:175)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AttachManager.attach(AttachManager.java:252)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AttachManager.attach(AttachManager.java:105)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.attach(BrokerImpl.java:3510)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.attach(DelegatingBroker.java:1214)
        at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.merge(EntityManagerImpl.java:878)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: Could it be that you are catching `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` rather than `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I changed the import to the openjpa one with the same results.

Comment: Try using "catch exception" instead of throwable for more details.